# Don't see why I'm getting a “Method Definition not found error”

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I had to move some existing code out of AppDelegate and place it in a common class so the app didn't have to be restarted.  Before I did the move, everything was building without errors and executing properly.  This is the code in my .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SingletonClass.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"

@interface CommonMethods : NSObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *unsortedNailArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *unsortedHairArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *unsortedCustomArray;

-(void) sortAndReloadServicesArray: (NSMutableArray *) textboxValues;
-(void) initalizeEnsembles;

-(void) displayAlert: (NSString *)alertTitle andMessage: (NSString *)alertMessage andViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController andTag:(int)tag;
-(NSMutableDictionary *) createStaffNamesDictionary;
-(NSMutableArray *) createStaffNamesArray;
-(BOOL)testConnectionToInternet;

-(void) initializeEnsembles;  //  definition that is missing?

- (NSString *) convert12HourTimeTo24HourTime: dateString andReturnType: (NSString *) dateOrDateTime;
- (NSString *) convert24HourTimeTo12HourTime: (NSString *)timeString;
- (NSNumber *) checkForApptOverlap: startTime andStopTime: stopTime andServiceTech: serviceTech;

@end
```

This is the associated .m file:

```
#import "CommonMethods.h"

@interface CommonMethods () <CDEPersistentStoreEnsembleDelegate>
@end

@implementation CommonMethods  {

CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble *ensemble;
CDEICloudFileSystem *cloudFileSystem;
}

@synthesize unsortedNailArray;
@synthesize unsortedHairArray;
@synthesize unsortedCustomArray;


#pragma mark - initializeEnsembles
-(void) initializeEnsembles  {  //  <---- here it is!

// set Ensembles verbose logging
CDESetCurrentLoggingLevel(CDELoggingLevelVerbose);

//  Ensemble: load the model
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel MR_newManagedObjectModelNamed:@"salonbook.momd"];  //  (xcdatamodeld)
[NSManagedObjectModel MR_setDefaultManagedObjectModel:model];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar method declaration

```
-(void) initalizeEnsembles;
```

without `i` after `sortAndReloadServicesArray`

Comment: Unbelievable!  Thank you so much! (I looked and looked at this for over an hour... )